# How to 'Remove sorting' from ExtJs Grid (2.3.0)

Tags: sorting, grid, extjs2

> **I have asked this question before two months but did not get an answer or even a comment/reply. So posting it again**

I have an ExtJs grid having sort functionality. **`(ExtJS 2.3.0)`**

I am sorting the columns as follows-

```
sort: function (colName, direction) {
       //
       // Some sort logic
       //
       this.fireEvent("datachanged", this);
}
```

This is working fine. The columns get sorted successfully.

Now I Have a button above my grid called 'Remove Sort'. On click of this button, I want to remove the applied sorting.

I tried-

```
removeSort: function (colName, direction) {
    // some logic
    //
    store.sortInfo = null; // This will remove the sortinfo (working as expected)
    grid.saveState(); // Saves the sort state (working as expected)
    this.fireEvent("datachanged", this);
}
```

In above code `store.sortInfo = null;` removes sortinfo and saves the state. But here "datachanged" is not firing. Means, it do not refreshes the grid on 'Remove sort' button.

I know I can use `reload()` function of grid but here I dont want to reload the grid. I want it should refresh the grid instantly just like it does when I sort the columns.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In `removeSort` try not to use keyword `this` but use direct references to the store object, eg. `store.fireEvent("datachanged", store );`